# how to accomplish an alarm clock or notification with my record sound

Tags: ios, push-notification

I want to accomplish function like an alarm clock or notification. When the app in background or not launch, app can give a notification or alert with sound which i record when the time i set is arriving.
I try to use UILocalNotification,but i found UILocalNotification only can use the sound in main bundle, cannot use the sound i record.

Answer (score 0):

To use a **UILocalNotification** with a **custom sound** use the folowing code:

```
UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];

[dateComp setDay:j+1];
[dateComp setHour:[[time objectAtIndex:0] integerValue]+offset];
[dateComp setMinute:[[time objectAtIndex:1] integerValue]];

NSLog(@"Year: %i, Month: %i, Day: %i, Time:%i:%i\n",[dateComp year], [dateComp month], 
                    [dateComp day], [dateComp hour], [dateComp minute]);

notif.fireDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComp];
notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

notif.alertBody = [names objectAtIndex: k];
notif.soundName = @"fireburn.caf";
```

Sometimes you need to clean the old notifications in order to have the new one with the custom sound.

So you have to clean the project, delete the app from the phone AND reboot the phone THEN it works.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! But the sound file "fireburn.caf" must in main bundle, i want to use AVAudioRecorder to record user's voice be used to soundName.